# Kerberos failures with accountname "host"

Tags: active-directory, authentication, domain-controller

Since May, our reporting tools are showing lots of failed authentication attempts against some of our DCs, for an account named `host` (which does not exist).

Event Viewer shows those failures as ID 4768 events:

```
A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.

Account Information:
    Account Name:       host
    Supplied Realm Name:    CONTOSO.COM
    User ID:            NULL SID

Service Information:
    Service Name:       krbtgt/CONTOSO.COM
    Service ID:     NULL SID

Network Information:
    Client Address:     ::1
    Client Port:        0

Additional Information:
    Ticket Options:     0x40810010
    Result Code:        0x6
    Ticket Encryption Type: 0xFFFFFFFF
    Pre-Authentication Type:    -

Certificate Information:
    Certificate Issuer Name:        
    Certificate Serial Number:  
    Certificate Thumbprint:
```

Sometimes, multiple are logged within the same second, then there's a "break" of a few minutes before it starts again - it's not a fixed schedule.

Uninstalling KB5014692 and KB5014805 on one of the DCs had stopped the errors occuring there. That's obviously not a solution, though.

Where could this originate from?

**Edit**: Suddenly, some of these events don't originate from `::1` anymore, but from the on-premise exchange server - but not on all DCs.
We are counting 25.000 failed authentication attempts a day because of this.

**Edit 2**: After spending months with M$ techsupport, their final statement is (quoted verbatim directly from a M$ support mail):

> Disable/Stop Event ID 4768
>
> You can disable or stop the audit Event
> 4768 by removing success and failure audit of Kerberos Authentication
> Service subcategory by using the following command.
>
> `auditpol /set /subcategory:"Kerberos Authentication Service" /success:disable`
>
> **and also, it can be safely ignored and for some scenarios enable**
> **everything in the advanced auditing will generate a tons of**
> **unnecessary logs**

This is the second time M$ support has suggested this.

To me, this is not a solution at all! Enhanced audit logging wasn't even enabled before we started noticing this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same issue.  Please see this article for a possible resolution:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-19-2022-kb5015019-os-build-14393-5127-out-of-band-8548dfda-38ba-4fb6-a7a3-42b86ac2cc81

In our case, we are still waiting for Microsoft to release a patch for this issue as their OOB patch does not work for the June release (which should have included it but does not appear to fully resolve the issue).

Comment: Did you get any news regarding this? I've been in contact with M$ support aswell, I've added their answer to the question.

Comment: Yes.  In our case, the issue ended up being related to our RADIUS server configuration.  The solution was to set the Framed-MTU setting in our Network Policy Server to 1344.  Apparently there was fragmentation of those RADIUS auth packets occurring which was causing the large number of RADIUS authentication failures.